# How can i unpack a list of dicts. in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The output of my code is a **list of dictionaries** and I want to **unpack** this list and print each dictionary **alone in one line** and tried the join method but I couldn't work with it and I also want to erase the single quote from text, I just want **the text to appear only** and i can't do that.
here's a sample of the list that i'm workin' with:

```
[{'نوع البطولة': 'الدوري المصري', 'الفريق الأول': 'المصري', 'الفريق الثانى': 'المقاولون العرب', 'وقت المباراة': '21-12-2022 - 17:00', 'النتيجة': '- - -'}, {'نوع البطولة': 'دوري الدرجة الثانية المصري', 'الفريق الأول': 'المنصورة', 'الفريق الثانى': 'نبروه', 'وقت المباراة': '21-12-2022 - 14:30', 'النتيجة': '- - -'}, {'نوع البطولة': 'دوري الدرجة الثانية المصري', 'الفريق الأول': 'الحمام', 'الفريق الثانى': 'المجد السكندري', 'وقت المباراة': '21-12-2022 - 14:30', 'النتيجة': '- - -'}, {'نوع البطولة': 'دوري الدرجة الثانية المصري', 'الفريق الأول': 'أبو قير للأسمدة', 'الفريق الثانى': 'هلال مطروح', 'وقت المباراة': '21-12-2022 - 14:30', 'النتيجة': '- - -'}]
```

i'm expecting to get a text like this:

```
'نوع البطولة': 'الدوري المصري', 'الفريق الأول': 'المصري', 'الفريق الثانى': 'المقاولون العرب', 'وقت المباراة': '21-12-2022 - 17:00', 'النتيجة': '- - -'
 نوع البطولة': 'دوري الدرجة الثانية المصري', 'الفريق الأول': 'المنصورة', 'الفريق الثانى': 'نبروه', 'وقت المباراة': '21-12-2022 - 14:30', 'النتيجة': '- - -'
, {'نوع البطولة': 'دوري الدرجة الثانية المصري', 'الفريق الأول': 'الحمام', 'الفريق الثانى': 'المجد السكندري', 'وقت المباراة': '21-12-2022 - 14:30', 'النتيجة': '- - -'
 'نوع البطولة': 'دوري الدرجة الثانية المصري', 'الفريق الأول': 'أبو قير للأسمدة', 'الفريق الثانى': 'هلال مطروح', 'وقت المباراة': '21-12-2022 - 14:30', 'النتيجة': '- - -'
```

Comment: There's nothing built-in that prints a dictionary without `{}` around it. You'll need to write your own code for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to print the entire array of dictionaries on **one line**. To do this, you can loop through the initial array, and print them, but specify an ending with the print statement, and don't let it end with a newline (`\n`).

In Python:

```
list = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
for i in list:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

If you do not want a space in-between each element, make the print statement `print(i, end='')`.

Comment: They want each dictionary on its own line, not the same line. They want all the properties on the same line, but no `{}` around it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in that prints a dictionary without its `{}` delimiters, so you need write your own formatter.

```
def format_dict(d):
    return ', '.join(f'{repr(key)}: {repr(value)}' for key, value in d.items())

for d in list_of_dicts:
    print(format_dict(d))
```